# Вывод свойств объекта в js

Tags: javascript, объекты

Имеется объект, нужно вывести все свойства со значениями. Разбирался отдельно со свойством `products` и запутался в циклах. Сейчас выводит по очереди сначала все `id`, потом так же по очереди все `name` и т.д. Как сделать, чтобы выводились значения `id, name, price, qty` первого элемента/объекта массива, затем второго и т.д.?

```js
var a = {
  "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Товар1",
      "price": 100,
      "qty": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Товар2",
      "price": 200,
      "qty": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Товар3",
      "price": 300,
      "qty": 1
    }
  ],
  "code": "0725422",
  "costDelivery": 5
};

var counter = 0;
for (var key in a.products) {
  counter++;
}

for (var key in a.products[0]) {
  for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    console.log("Ключ: " + key + ", значение: " + a.products[i][key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: убери первый цикл и counter. Хотя вообще ерунда написана :) повезло, что количество ключей в `a` совпадает с количеством элементов в `a.products`

Comment: Проглядел,исправил немного. Тоже ерунда?) Просто если убрать первый, то как количество элементов в массиве считать?

Comment: первый цикл можно заменить на `var counter = a.products.length`.

Comment: на самом деле непонятно, что ты хочешь получить в итоге. ты можешь использовать метод [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) для обхода элементов в массиве, можешь использовать [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) чтобы получить массив со всеми ключами объекта, и затем свернуть его в строку, с помощью [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Сейчас выводит `id:1, id:2, id3, name:"Товар1", name: "Товар2"` и т.д. А нужно, чтобы как в массиве, поочередно все свойства каждого элемента/объекта массива `products`, а затем уже самого объекта `a`.

Comment: поменяй местами `for (var key in a.products[0]) {` и `for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {`

Comment: Боже мой. Спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = a.products;
var keys = [];
var i = 0;
for( i; i <= a.length; i++ ){
    for(var k in a[i]) {
        var val = a[i][k];
        keys.push( k + '=>' + val );
    }
}
console.log( keys );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавь описание того, что происходит в твоем коде, и почему ты думаешь, что это поможет?

Comment: и еще обрати внимание, что судя по всему набор ключей не постоянен

Comment: znachenie 'products' ne menyayetsa, a shas uje nabor klyuchey vse sobiraetsa v keys

Comment: _добавь описание того, что происходит в твоем коде_ в сам ответ.

Comment: плюс у тебя ошибка в условии цикла. И кроме того уже давно `var` можно писать внутри секции инициализации for, вынос переменной `i` из цикла странно выглядит

Comment: знаю. так напиши норм ответ сам)

Comment: зачем, если уже есть один ответ, который просто в порядок надо привести

Answer (score -1):

```
for(let i in a.products){
    let item=a.products[i]
        for (let i in item){
            console.log(i + " : " + item[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]